# Hosting MVC 4 site with Google Drive Client API on AppHarbor hang on oAuth authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-oauth, appharbor, google-drive-api

I am playing with Google Drive Client API with MVC 4 web project. The code works great locally with IIS express. However, when I deploy the site to AppHarbor, the oAuth authentication hang. I tried both web client credentials and installed app client credentials. What do I need to do to get it working?

Here is the code snippet for Authentication:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = { Client_ID set in Google developer console},
                ClientSecret = { Client secret in Google developer console},
            },
            new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;

         //Create the service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Google Drive Reader",
        });

         //More code goes here

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I figured this out and put an answer to this question in case others may what to know.

Comment: Please include fiddler / firebug network panel / chromedev network panel / etc monitoring of the HTTP requests.

Comment: Does the authentication page pop up at all?

Comment: To Chris: the authentication is on the server side inside the controller. Since the site is running at AppHarbor, I am not sure how i can proxy appharbor's http requests.

Comment: To DalmTo: the authentication page does not pop up at all. It works on local IIS express with Google installed app client ID. I tried both installed app client ID and web app client ID on AppHarbor, neither worked. The app is at this URL: http://gdrive-dev.apphb.com/, in case you want to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

First of all, the method I used in the question works only for standalone applications, does not work for MVC applications.  MVC application should follow the method documented here:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications

One important thing to notice is that web application client ID should be used, and the Redirect URL needs to be the URL to your AuthCallbackController.

Second, there is a problem in the Sample code: in HomeController

```
 public async Task IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Should be:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Third: make sure adding the following appSetting to web.config so that AppHarbor sends correct redirect url.

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="aspnet:UseHostHeaderForRequestUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

After that, it worked for me both locally with IIS Express and on AppHarbor.